# Flash file upload in Domino and CDN

Tags: file, flash, upload, cdn, lotus-domino

I,m using the flash file upload solution to attach files in Domino applications. 
Basically it works with dojo and flash.
It was working normally. The Security Information area decided to change the browser security (IE 8)to high.
The solution uses CDN and stopped work. The question is:

Is there way to copy the content from CDN to local network? How?
Is there a personalized configuration in IE that permits access to CDN site?

Thanks a lot!

Marcus.

Comment: Your question is **Not** really clear, is it Notes application or web access application ? moving code from CDN to your server is really not a problem copy the code to your Domino/data directory is you question ? What is the error you get with IE high security ?

Comment: Hi! It´s a Domino web access aplication. How to identify the code to copy? The error is: Could not load cross-domain resources and the dojo button doesn´t load. I copied the file dojo.xd.js from CDN to application, but it has some url references.

Comment: you need to edit the links and put your server in place